# Object::property ( const char * name ) const returning empty QVariant

Tags: qt, enums, qproperty, qgadget

My class has enum property, i wish to access this property using `QObject*`. When calling `QVariant QObject::property ( const char * name ) const` return value is empty `QVariant` of enum type.

Consider the following code:

```
/* Interface class */
class IFoo
{
Q_GADGET
public:
  Q_ENUMS(ColorType)

  typedef enum
  {
    COLOR_RED = 0,
    COLOR_BLUE
  } ColorType;

  virtual QString Name(void) const = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(IFoo::ColorType)

class Foo
  : public IFoo
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Foo(void) 
  {
    qint32 typeId = qRegisterMetaType<IFoo::ColorType>("ColorType");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<int>(IFoo::ColorType);
  }
  virtual QString Name(void) const { return _name; }

  void SetColor(ColorType color) { _color = color; }
  ColorType Color(void) const { return _color; }
  QString ColorString(void) const { return _color == IFoo::COLOR_RED ? "Red" : "Blue"; }

  Q_PROPERTY(IFoo::ColorType Color READ Color WRITE SetColor)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString ColorString READ ColorString)

private:
  ColorType _color;
  QString _name;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  Foo f;
  f.SetColor(IFoo::COLOR_RED);

  qDebug() << f.property("Color"); // Returns QVariant(IFoo::ColorType, ) 
  qDebug() << f.property("ColorString"); // Returns QString(Red)
}
```

Why does property return empty QVariant value? String wrapper property works as it should.

Comment: Is it really empty? Have you tried calling QVariant::value<IFoo::Color>()? Also, have you tried using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?

Comment: Seems u are right .. QVariant::value<IFoo::Color>() returned correct int value. Unfortunately that doesn't help me much, or is it possible to get enum type from QVariant and insert it in QVariant::value<T>()?

Comment: What do you mean? QVariant::value<IFoo::Color>() already does return the enum type.

Comment: I wish to use this in for loop and bind the property to a widget, so would need to have some kind of general enum property converter. Ps: Added Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, doesn't help but it's needed for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few mistakes on the code that prevent it from compiling:

1. Using Q_OBJECT without inheriting from QObject.
2. `qRegisterMetaType` is not needed if you use Q_ENUM (which I used to replace Q_ENUMS, which is the old version, deprecated in 5.5).
3. `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` was being passed an int as template argument instead of the type to register, and the argument to the function (not template argument) should be a string, which is optional anyway; but not a type.

Full source:

```cpp
#include <QtCore> // Just for the test. Use more fine grained includes.

/* Interface class */
class IFoo
{
Q_GADGET
public:

  enum ColorType
  {
    COLOR_RED = 0,
    COLOR_BLUE
  };
  Q_ENUM(ColorType)

  virtual QString Name(void) const = 0;
};

class Foo : public QObject, public IFoo
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Foo(void) 
  {
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<IFoo::ColorType>();
  }
  virtual QString Name(void) const { return _name; }

  void SetColor(ColorType color) { _color = color; }
  ColorType Color(void) const { return _color; }
  QString ColorString(void) const { return _color == IFoo::COLOR_RED ? "Red" : "Blue"; }

  Q_PROPERTY(IFoo::ColorType Color READ Color WRITE SetColor)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString ColorString READ ColorString)

private:
  ColorType _color;
  QString _name;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  Foo f;
  f.SetColor(IFoo::COLOR_RED);

  qDebug() << f.property("Color"); // Returns QVariant(IFoo::ColorType, ) 
  qDebug() << f.property("ColorString"); // Returns QString(Red)
  // Now returns:
  // QVariant(IFoo::ColorType, "COLOR_RED")
  // QVariant(QString, "Red")
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that moc tool is unable to generate strings for respective values. IMO problem is `typedef`.
Try simple `enum` inside of class:

```
enum ColorType {
  COLOR_RED = 0,
  COLOR_BLUE
};
```

Or `typedef` with `enum` keyword:

```
typedef enum {
  COLOR_RED = 0,
  COLOR_BLUE
} ColorType;
```

I'm pretty sure that missing `enum` keyword confuses the moc tool.

Comment: no enum keyword was a typo, trying out without typedef .. same, i guess i have to use StringWrapper.